# How to setup solr cloud with 2 shards 1 leader and 1 replica and with zookeeper on different machines?

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I'm still confused on setting up a solr cloud cluster. The one in the tutorial are setup for localhost binded to different ports. But I wanna know how would it be like using different machines. What do I need?  Do I need to extract the downloaded Solr to each machine? Should I setup zookeeper first and set the configuration? Should zookeeper be installed on a different machine which is not a Solr server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tutorial is a lot closer to what you need:

http://solr.pl/en/2013/03/11/solrcloud-howto-2/

If you don't want to run a separate Zookeeper, you can run the embedded Zookeeper on one of your Solr instances by passing -Dzkrun on this instance, and -DzkHost on the other instances to point to the first one.

Comment: I've read the article, though I have an additional question.

Say, I wanna setup a 3 zookeeper instances to form an ensemble which should be installed independently from solr. does that 3 zookeeper instances needs to be on 3 different machines?

Comment: You don't technically need 3 different machines for the 3 zookeepers, but of course your fault tolerance will be lower if you set all 3 on a single machine; your zookeeper ensemble will keep working if one JVM goes down, but it will disappear if the machine goes down. If you use 3 machines (recommended config), one machine can go down without interrupting the service.